# SSRS : Background color of a line inside a matrix cell

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, line, background-color

I have an SSRS report in which I have a matrix and a line Inside a cell of this matrix but I would like to change the background color of the cell and I don't know how to do it as the line control does not have a background color property.

[Report Designer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyEs9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the background colour of the **matrix**, the line object will use this background colour. It may mean your have to set the 'white' cells to white manually but it should get round the problem.